# Determining where a function is complex differentiable

Tags: complex-analysis

I have a homework question, and I'm having a hard time interpreting it.

Question: Where is the function $f(x+iy)=x^4y^5+ixy^3$ complex differentiable? Determine the derivative in such points.

My first plan was to find a region for which the following theorem applied:

Suppose $f=u+iv$ is a complex-valued function defined on an open set $\Omega$. If $u$ and $v$ are continuously differentiable and satisfy the Cauch-Riemann equations on $\Omega$, then $f$ is holomorphic on $\Omega$ and $f'(z)=\frac{\partial f}{\partial z}$.

Of course, $u$ and $v$ are going to be continously differentiable; the only question is, on what region are the Cauchy-Riemann equations satisfied?

So, I found that the Cauchy-Riemann equations in this case are the following:

$4x^3y^5=3xy^2$ and $5x^4y^4=-y^3$

and the only point at which these equations are satisfied is $(0,0)$.

There's a converse to this theorem, but a lone point is not a region, so I'm not sure if either of these theorems are relevant.

Is the only way to go back and find at which points

$lim_{h\to0} \frac{f(z_{0}+h)-f(z_{0})}{h}$

exists?

Thanks.

Comment: The function is complex differentiable exactly on the on the real axis (where $y = 0$), not just at the origin.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, you don't need to check the limit (although you can if you want to). The existence of the complex limit is *equivalent* to the CR equations (when the function is continuously differentiable, as in this case).

Assuming your equations are correct, notice that there are more points you've missed - you divided by $y$ not taking into account the fact that $y$ could be 0. So for starters the entire line $\{y=0\}$ satisfies those equations. Finally, it's easy to show that those are the only points that satisfy the equations.

Comment: They are not completely equivalent -- it is possible for the CR equations to be satisfied even when the complex derivative does not exist, such as for $f(x+iy)=\min(|x|,|y|)$ at $0$, where all terms in Cauchy-Riemann are zero.

Comment: @HenningMakholm, indeed, although (and I should have stated that more clearly, I'll update momentarily) in this case where everything is smooth, as the OP already noted, they are equivalent.

Comment: Thanks. I don't know how I missed that the equations are always satisfied when y=0. It's quite obvious now.

Answer (score 2):

It's easy to prove that if at any particular point the function does *not* satisfy the Cauchy-Riemann equations, then its complex derivative cannot exist at that point -- or contrapositively: *If* the complex derivative exists at some point, *then* the Cauchy-Riemann equations are satisfied there.

Consider $h$ going towards $0$ along either the real or the imaginary axis. If the complex difference quotient has the same limit in both these cases (as it must have if the *general* limit for $h\to 0$ exists), then by a very simple calculation that means that the Cauchy-Riemann equation are satisfied.

The theorem you quote is (more or less) the converse of this easy case, and is the harder direction.